# How do I obtain the SUSY Transformations from Poisson Brackets?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, supersymmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, field-theory, poisson-brackets

In [Friedman's and Van Proyen's Supergravity textbook](http://books.google.ie/books/about/Supergravity.html?id=7ANrOHJLTjMC&redir_esc=y) it is explained how one can get the supersymmetry transformations using the conserved currents. Specifically this is in section 6 where we are dealing with $\mathcal{N}=1$ SUSY in 4 dimensions (this is the non-interacting Wess-Zumino model). The spinor charge is given by

$$ Q_{\alpha} = \int d^3\vec{x} \, J_{\alpha}^0(\vec{x},t). \tag{6.5}$$

In page 112 they claim that the SUSY transformations are as following

\begin{eqnarray}
\delta \phi(x) &=& \{ \bar{\epsilon}Q, \phi(x) \}_{\text{P.B.}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bar{\epsilon}\psi(x) \tag{6.14} \\
\delta \psi(x) &=&  \{ \bar{\epsilon}Q, \psi(x) \}_{\text{P.B.}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\gamma \cdot \partial +m)\phi \epsilon 
\end{eqnarray}

As you see, they define these transformations via the Poisson brackets

$$ \{ f,g \} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.$$

I've tried to prove this by computing the Poisson brackets, but I keep getting stuck. In particular when the derivative acts on $J$, surely it will give zero since $\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}=0$.

1. Can anyone explain where my reasoning is incorrect?
2. Can anyone give an easy general argument as to why Poisson brackets are the correct way to get the transformations? I haven't come across this idea before.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: It's a completely general fact that the conserved charge of a symmetry generates the symmetry via the Poisson bracket. What is the conceptual question here?

Comment: Please, I did not know that. I am not sure I have seen PB before in usage with symmetries. Rather for the dynamics of a system through the Hamiltonian.  It is also technical rather than conceptual because I am not sure if upon taking the Poisson bracket I act with it normally, as it is its definition, upon the supercharge and what the integral gives although I suspect a $\delta$ function to appear.

Comment: Have edited - I think this question should be left open for now, since it has got a conceptual basis and involves a concrete calculation that the OP has made some attempt at. I will provide an answer later when I get a moment!